# How to pass a local struct as parameter to pthread_create?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, scope, pthreads

The following function doesn't work. `pin_thread_function` sometimes receive garbage instead of the struct data. What is wrong? I know that is some basic scope related problem, but I can't explain.

```
typedef void (*state_callback_t)(int state);

struct pin_thread_params
{
    char pin[3 + 1];
    state_callback_t callback_onchange;
};

extern int pin_monitor_create(const char * pin,
        state_callback_t callback_onchange)
{
    int ret;
    unsigned long int thread;
    struct pin_thread_params params;

    //Setup struct
    strcpy(params.pin, "123");
    params.callback_onchange = callback_onchange;

    //Create thread with struc as parameter
    ret = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, pin_thread_function, &params);
    if (!ret)
    {
        ret = pthread_detach(thread);
    }

    return ret;
}

static void * pin_thread_function(void * context)
{
    struct pin_thread_params params;
    memcpy(&params, context, sizeof(params));

    //Sometimes the correct string, most time garbage 
    printf("Started monitoring %s", params.pin);
}
```

When params is malloc'ed before pthread_create, everything works fine, like this:

```
...
    struct pin_thread_params * params;

    //Setup struct with malloc
    params = malloc(sizeof(struct pin_thread_params));
    strcpy(params->pin, "123");
    params->callback_onchange = callback_onchange;
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`struct pin_thread_params params` is statically allocated and the address of it is **not** safe to use once the scope of it is over (i.e. after `pin_monitor_create` has returned). It may happen that sometimes the thread execution starts before the `pin_monitor_create` has exited and you see the valid data in `params`. However, the dynamically allocated memory is from heap and will be usable until you free it, so you always get valid data in `params` within `pin_thread_function` .

Comment: So `params` is lost just after `pthread_create`. I was almost sure that it would be gone only at the end of function `pin_monitor_create`...;-( Am I missing some basic scope concept?

Comment: No, read what he wrote again. It is gone at the end of `pin_monitor_create`.

Comment: @natenho It's not lost after `pthread_create`, it's lost after `pin_monitor_create`. You have no direct control over the thread scheduler. If the main thread finishes executing `pin_thread_create` before the `pin_thread_function` thread runs, you will have junk data. If you get lucky and the `pin_thread_function` thread executes before the main thread finishes, you will see your string. Or on a multi-core chip, the 2 threads really could run in parallel. A context switch could happen at any time. You must employ some thread synchronization techniques.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not particularly knowledgeable about pthreads (can't just comment quite yet), but you are passing a pointer to stack allocated memory to the thread which will eventually be clobbered by proceeding function calls.

Comment: Shouldn't params and the stack live until the end of pin_monitor_create?

Comment: parameters ON the stack live until pin monitor create is over with.

Comment: Yes, but you are depending upon pin_thread_function() to make the copy before pin_monitor_create() finishes. Which is why _sometimes_ you get garbage and other times it works. You are depending upon the scheduler. mallocing would the proper way to handle this.

Comment: @natenho yes they do. The problem is, as both these answers say, `pin_monitor_create` doesn't wait for `pin_thread_function` to finish executing. As far as I can tell from the man page, `pthread_detach` is not a blocking call. So you create `params` on the stack, start the thread, and now you have a race condition between `pin_thread_function` and the remainder of `pin_monitor_create`. Once `pin_monitor_create` returns, `params` is no longer valid. If you do this you'll need some kind of synchronization to ensure `pin_thread_create` will wait on `pin_thread_function` to finish before returning

Comment: @yano, Perfect. Now I see where is the race condition, I was not considering that the `pin_monitor_create` could return before the thread access to the params pointer, your comment has been very helpful.

Comment: @natenho Cool! Threads get tricky quickly. I recommend reading this tutorial, it's very good, I'm always referring back to it: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/